# How to reload an eclipse update site programmatically

Tags: java, eclipse, rcp

instead of using the GUI can I reload an update site programatically for eclipse rcp application [image]

I want to reload these update site before starting the provisioning process

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: That appears to call `IMetadataRepositoryManager.refreshRepository`. The page you show is `org.eclipse.equinox.p2.ui.RepositoryManipulationPage`, look at the `refreshRepository` method to see exactly what it does.